# How to compress wav file in iOS phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I my phonegap app (phonegap 3.1.0), I record an audio file in wav format (it's an obligation) but I notice that the bitrate is 44000 (android use 8000 bitrate) so the file is very huge and it's a problem to upload it to a server.

Do you have any advice or solution to reduce the file before filetransfert?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little late but you may try this plugin: https://github.com/williamtdr/cordova-zip-plugin